# Attribute returns Undefined in Table

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm quite new to JQuery and have encountered following problem.
I am making a website that displays a table where rows with colspan=4 are hidden.
When you click a row the row below (which was previously hidden) should slide out and the row that was clicked should have a red background and white text-color. If that same row is clicked again, the row below should toggleSlide again and the clicked row should return to the previous layout (in my case white BG and black text).

The slideToggle works but problems arise with the colors. HTML en JQuery follows.

**HTML:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
       <td>Test 1</td>
       <td>Test 2</td>
       <td>Test 3</td>
       <td>Test 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td colspan="4"> This is the first hidden row</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
table{
border-collapse: collapse;
}

td{
color: black;
background-color: white;
}
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(function () {
    $("td[colspan=4]").hide();
    $("table").click(function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        var $target = $(event.target);
        if ($target.closest("td").attr("colspan") > 1) {
            } else {
                $target.closest("tr").next().find("td").slideToggle("fast");

            }


    }
    );
});
```

Now above code should work but when I insert a if-else to check if the hidden row is hidden or not I often get Undefined or Visible all the time (I checked through alerts). Same if I check the color-attribute for the clicked row, I often get Undefined.

I think I need something like:

**Checking the attributes of the clicked tr:**

```
if($target.closest("tr").attr("color") === "black"){$target.closest("tr").css("color","white").css("background-color","red");}
else{
$target.closest("tr").css("color","black").css("background-color","white");}
```

OR

**Checking if the hidden row is actually hidden:**

```
if($target.closest("tr").next().find("td").is(":visible")){$target.closest("tr").css("color","white").css("background-color","red");}
else{
$target.closest("tr").css("color","black").css("background-color","white");}
```

I apologize if this question is too vague. I can eloborate more if necessary.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qeg2zb7e/

Comment: Where is your css code?

Comment: add a jsfiddle working link so that we can check whats happening

Comment: Hint: `tr.selected { background-color: red } tr.hidden { display: none }` `.addClass("selected")`, `.removeClass("hidden")`

Comment: Added CSS and JSFiddle.

Comment: It might be a bad idea to call `event.stopPropagation();` on all clicks on the table  the effect of which is *Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.*  ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this jQuery code in else condition

**$target.closest("tr").find("td").toggleClass('bg-text');**

And also put (bg-text) class into css  style.

```js
$(function () {
  $("td[colspan=4]").hide();
  $("table").click(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    var $target = $(event.target);
    if ($target.closest("td").attr("colspan") > 1) {
    }
    else {
      //add this code
      $target.closest("tr").find("td").toggleClass('bg-text');
      
      $target.closest("tr").next().find("td").slideToggle("fast");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
table{
  border-collapse: collapse;
 }
 td{
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
 }

/*toggle class for red background and white text color*/
 .bg-text{
  background: red;
  color: white;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <title>Menu Collapse</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
   <table class="table table-bordered">
      <tr>
        <td>Test 1</td>
        <td>Test 2</td>
        <td>Test 3</td>
        <td>Test 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="4"> This is the first hidden row - 1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Test 1.1</td>
        <td>Test 2.1</td>
        <td>Test 3.1</td>
        <td>Test 4.1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="4"> This is the first hidden row 1.1</td>
      </tr>
              <tr>
        <td>Test 1.2</td>
        <td>Test 2.3</td>
        <td>Test 3.4</td>
        <td>Test 4.5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="4"> This is the first hidden row 1.2</td>
      </tr>
   </table>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly now :)

Comment: Ok :) @ThomasDM

Answer (score 0):

A simpler approach might be something like this:

#### [jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/99n2o6wc/)

```js
$('#my-table').on('click', '.open-row',function(){
   var $targets = $('.target-row');
   var $triggers = $('.open-row');
   var $this=$(this).toggleClass('active');
   var currentIndex = $triggers.index($this);
   var $target = $targets.eq(currentIndex).slideToggle('fast');
});
```

```css
.open-row.active{
  background-color:red;
  
}
.target-row{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="my-table">
    <tr class="open-row">
       <td>Test 1</td>
       <td>Test 2</td>
       <td>Test 3</td>
       <td>Test 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="target-row">
       <td colspan="4"> This is the first hidden row</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

---

### Explaination:

- `$('#my-table').on('click', '.open-row',function(){` Listens for clicks on #my-table and checks if you clicked a child with the class `open-row`
- `var $targets = $('.target-row');` gets a collection of all the hidden rows
- `var $triggers = $('.open-row');` gets a collection of all the clickable rows
- `var $this=$(this).toggleClass('active');` toggles the class `active` on the clicked element
- `var currentIndex = $triggers.index($this);` This returns the index or position of the clicked element in the array of clickable elements
- `$targets.eq(currentIndex).slideToggle('fast');` The line above gets passed into eq here which returns the target row that is at the same index as the clicked row ie the row below the clicked row then calls slideToggle on it

Comment: Thank you for your answer but sadly even with copy pasten your code and changing the necessary things to fit it, it did'nt work. Most likely the fault is with me since you snippet works. I'll look into it further at a later time. Thank you for yor time.

Comment: @ThomasDM note that it requires that you add the id `my-table` to the table (or some other id) and add the classes to the `tr`s. Id bet one of those is missing